# Black Screen with "Input signal out of range" message, after AMD graphic driver installation [13.10]

Tags: 13.10, grub2, ati, radeon

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 64bit alongside Windows 7 64bit, and both ran fine. Then I installed AMD graphic driver for my video card radeon R9 270 following the 3rd(manual) procedure given in these [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD).

- I installed AMD catalyst 13.12.

Everything installed successfully according to the link, but then, after restarted my system and booting into Ubuntu I got a **black screen** with:

```
"Input signal out of range"
```

- My monitor doesn't support 1920x1080, it support 1366x768 natively.

I tried booting again and entered <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, then:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
[or] gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
[or] sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

but every time it gave the same result:

```
"Cannot open display"
```

I tried searching for a solution this whole day but couldn't find something useful, so please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: try to edit file with screen-oriented text editor like vi: sudo vi /etc/default/grub

Comment: I suppose the resolution of the screen is beyond your monitor's resolution. Do you hear the login sound? If yes, then type your password and press enter. Now you will be in the desktop. Now press Alt+Ctrl+t. Now type "xrandr -s 1024x768"(without the quotes). Instead of 1024x768 you can even use other resolutions.